# Usable cell phone network in Montenegro Zabljak area for calls and data

Tags: cellphones, montenegro

I would like to get a prepaid SIM card for my stay in Zabljak area, Montenegro. What network should I be looking for to get a good coverage and is there data (EDGE, 3G, UMTS) available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy [T-Mobile Montenegro Prepaid card](http://www.t-mobile.me/eng/prepaid.aspx). They have good coverage in Zabljak area ([coverage map](http://www.telekom.me/content/pokrivenost.jpg)) and they offer prepaid data packages:

- 1 day internet with 100 MB included costs 0,5 EUR
- 7 days internet with 500 MB included costs 3 EUR
- 15 days internet with 1 GB included costs 5 EUR

Also when you buy a prepaid voucher, you get a data bonus (between 50 MB and 2 GB)

Another option is to buy a Telenor prepaid card. More than 99% of populated territory of Montenegro is covered with their network ([coverage map](http://www.telenor.me/en/About-Telenor/Network/)). It seems that they offer only GPRS for prepaid cards (0,06 EUR / 100 KB)

Comment: Tmobile offers a 15 day internet option which includes 1024Mb for ~ 5€. Maybe the prices you quoted are just the vouchers having a monetary value and a added bonus of mobile data? see: http://www.t-mobile.me/upload/CjenovnikENG.pdf page 8.

Comment: you're right, I will update my answer